# WPF TCP/IP Client server communication

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here I'm trying to implement a TCP/IP client server Communication in a WPF application. I see many examples in console applications and forms, but not in WPF applications.
And also I don't know how to stream messages between a client and server. Could anybody help me out with source code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTGqD.png)

```
    Client code

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using WPFclient;

    namespace WPFClient
      {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        protected ClientProp WpfClient_;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Btncnnct1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TxtBoxIp1.Text = "192.168.0.150";
            //TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            this.WpfClient_ = new ClientProp(ipAddress: (this.TxtBoxIp1.Text), portNumber: 138);
            this.WpfClient_.BeginPrepareTCPClient();
            WpfClient_.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(this.TxtBoxIp1.Text), port: 137);
            TxtBoxInfo1.Text = "connected" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        private void BtnSnd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TxtBoxMsg1.Text);
            NetworkStream networkStream = WpfClient_.GetStream();
            StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(TxtBoxMsg1.Text);
            stream.Write(TxtBoxMsg1.Text, 0, TxtBoxMsg1.Text.Length);
            TxtBoxInfo1.Text += $"Server : {TxtBoxMsg1.Text}{Environment.NewLine}";
          
        }
```

Help me out to communicate between a server and client in a WPF application. I checked out many methods like stream, network stream, dispatcher, etc.... I couldn't understand the code. I have created two WPF Applications one for server and one for client.
[enter image description here][2]  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYKaq.png

```
    Server Code

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.IO;

    namespace ServerWPF
     {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
     /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
        private string line;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
        private void BtnStrt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TxtBoxIp.Text = "192.168.0.150";
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(TxtBoxIp.Text), port: 137);
            server.Start();
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            TxtBoxInfo.Text = "Server Connected" + Environment.NewLine;
            BtnStrt.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnSend.IsEnabled = true;
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);         
        }
        private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        
        }
```

Comment: Ditch low level TCP, and go for mature reliable technologies. Like anything else, such as grpc, signalr, 《insert stuff here》

Comment: i have got to know about this and should be able to communicate Client and server application.And should try it in two different systems.

Comment: The communication aspect is no different between WinForms and WPF (and even Console).

Comment: what am i missing,can you provide source code so that i could understand and implement.@KlausGütter

Comment: You wrote it already in your question: there are tons of example out there.

Comment: share me out some example links.@KlausGütter

Comment: The server is a wpf app rather than a web app?

Comment: Are client and server apps going to be on different machines or the same?

Comment: yess  both the server and client are Wpf App.@Andy

Comment: I checked out an example done with console application.I want to implement the same in Wpf app(server and client).@Andy

Comment: So your entire purpose is just to try it out?

Comment: You can host web api in any app. Because it's a web server kind of thing mostly you'll see web apps but google hard enough and you'll find an article or two explains hosting in a desktop app.  You can host the web api in both and call each other or one and call from the other. Use httpclient to make call. Start reading here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: @Viswa, I'd aggree with TheGeneral to use a technology like signalr. Check out [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fLnF7VBjas) to start with.

Comment: purpose is not just to try it out.I have to implement it for a work@Andy

Comment: first i have to communicate the server and client using local ip in a system and then i have to try to communicate server and client from two different systems with different ip.@Andy

Comment: i will try it out @Jeffery

Comment: It might make things a little easier for you. A simple to understand package. https://github.com/jchristn/SuperSimpleTcp

Comment: it is easy with the package.But it should be done without the package.@OzgurSaklanmaz